# Silverlight app freezes when simply adding a textblock to the layoutroot

Tags: c#, silverlight

I cannot understand why in the hell this simple silverlight application freezes up. Here is the code:

```
namespace test
{
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    TextBlock txtword;
    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        txtword = new TextBlock();
        txtword.Text = "TEST";

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtword);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtword.Text = "SuperDuper";
    }

}
}
```

After the textblock is added to the layoutroot if you try to hover or click on the button you can tell that the app has frozen for some reason. Any idea what is going on here??

If i add the text block in the XAML i am able to change its text property in the button click. LayoutRoot.Children.Add() is causing the app to freeze..

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce any freezing.  Which Silverlight version are you using?  Which Visual Studio version?  Can you reproduce this problem on more than one computer?

Comment: I am using silverlight 5, visual studio 2010, and i was able to produce this problem on my laptop and on my work computer.

Comment: @LukeWoodward you didn't declare the textblock in the XAML did you? That actually works for me, but if i try to create and add a textblock in the code behind it doesn't work. Edit: let me rephrase: It DOES work but after the textblock shows up on the screen i can no longer interact with the UI anymore.

Comment: Is your `LayoutRoot` a `Grid`?  If so, and the `TextBlock` is on top of the button (note that the `TextBlock` will fill the grid by default, even if its text won't), then the `TextBlock` will be what gets clicked on, not the button.  Does setting the `HorizontalAlignment` and/or `VerticalAlignment` of the `TextBlock` to values other than `Stretch` help?

Comment: My `LayoutRoot` is indeed a `Grid` but the `Textblock` is not on top of the button. The problem happens when the `Textblock` is added programmatically however. Edit: however, after setting the horizontal and vertical alginment properties of the textblock in the c# code the program works. This was driving me absolutely crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your comments it seems the XAML  in MainPage.xaml is something like the following:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button Content="Do stuff" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

After adding the `TextBlock`, either in code or in XAML, you effectively end up with the following:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button Content="Do stuff" Click="Button_Click" />
    <TextBlock Text="TEST" />
</Grid>
```

Your `Grid` doesn't specify any `ColumnDefinition`s or `RowDefinition`s, so you have a 1 × 1 grid with all child controls of the `Grid` given the entire width and height of the grid.

As neither your `Button` nor your `TextBlock` specify a z-index value (using `Canvas.ZIndex`), their z-order is defined by their position within the grid's `Children`.  The `TextBlock` comes after the `Button`, so it is the one that is 'on top'.

The `TextBlock` may contain only a tiny amount of text, but the `TextBlock` itself will still fill the `Grid`.  `TextBlock`s do not automatically resize to fit the text they contain and nothing else.  Your `Button` appears not to work because the `TextBlock` is on top of it and receives all of the mouse events.  `TextBlock`s are static controls that do nothing in response to any mouse event, and this should explain why your app is appearing to freeze.

Setting the `HorizontalAlignment` and/or `VerticalAlignment` of the `TextBlock` to a value other than `Stretch` stops the `TextBlock` being given the entire width and height of the `Grid` and allows the `Button` to receive mouse events.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. It's embarassing how much this was bothering me.